# Rails accepts nested attributes: Reject if association has blank associated item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any way to reject nested attributes checking for the presence of a deep associated object? Right now i am trying something like this:

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :has_answer?

  # REJECT ANSWER IF ASSOCIATED ANSWER TYPE IS BLANK
  def has_answer?
    answers.each do |a|
      a.answer_open.present? || a.answer_rating.present?
    end
  end
end

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :answer_open, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :answer_rating, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_open, reject_if: proc { |a| a['response'].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_rating, reject_if: proc { |a| a['response'].blank? }
end
```

Comment: Please clarify, are you asking about rejecting nested attributes based on a deeply nested object in _the passed attributes themselves_, or based on a deeply nested object that is pre-existing in the database. Are you trying to "chain" the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` lines in each class..?

Comment: I am asking about rejecting nested attributes based on a deeply nested object in the passed attributes as my example shows clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not too far off. Per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html, the `reject_if` option is correct here.

However, your `has_answer?` method is checking the answers *that are already associated to the submission.* You should check the value of answers_attributes instead. Look for the examples using `posts_attributes` in the above link. One of them uses a `reject_if` check with nested attributes.

Also, your `has_answer?` method is returning an array, which will always be true. You probably want something like:

```
attributes['answers_attributes'].any? do |a|
  a['answer_open'].present? || a['answer_rating'].present?
end
```

Though that snippet probably needs to be tailored a bit to the specifics of your app.

Comment: Any idea why i would get undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass in your above snippet?

Comment: You might get that if `attributes` doesn't have an 'answers_attributes' key. If `attributes['answers_attributes'] # => nil`, then `attributes['answers_attributes'].any?` is the same as `nil.any?`, which doesn't work. Trying inspecting `attributes` at the beginning of the method and see what it looks like. For these cases you can just add a check to see if the key is present at the beginning of the method.

Comment: Now i got it working as i needed thanks. Pls upvote my question.

Answer (score 0):

`answers.each do` should be `self.answers.each do`

Comment: Can you provide more context/information to substantiate your answer.